# Calling supertype methods in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm reading book The Principles of Object-Oriented Javascript and I'm stuck at part, where accessing supertype methods is explained. I have defined two functions on super prototype(redeclared toString and new function getArea) and extended them whit child class, in which i want to change super methods while using their return value. Code look like this:

```
function Rectangle(length, width) {
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}
Rectangle.prototype.getArea = function () {
    return this.length * this.width;
};
Rectangle.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "[Rectangle " + this.length + "x" + this.width + "]";
};

// inherits from Rectangle
function Square(size) {
    Rectangle.call(this, size, size);
}
Square.prototype = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        value: Square,
        writable: true
    }
});

// call the supertype method
Square.prototype.toString = function () {
    var text = Rectangle.prototype.toString.call(this);
    return text.replace("Rectangle", "Square");
};
Square.prototype.getArea = function () {
    var area = Rectangle.prototype.getArea().call(this);
    return area * 2;
};

var rectangle = new Rectangle(2, 2);
console.log(rectangle); //instance of Rectangle
console.log(rectangle.toString()); // [Rectangle 2x2]
console.log(rectangle.getArea()); //4

var square = new Square(2);
console.log(square); //instance of Square
console.log(square.toString()); // [Square 2x2]
console.log(square.getArea()); //expected 8, got ERROR
```

Problem is, `square.getArea()` throws the error

> undefined is not a function

Can someone explain me why? Why `toString` works and `getArea` not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line

```
var area = Rectangle.prototype.getArea().call(this);
```

you are trying to invoke *the result of `getArea()`* as a function with `call` (which is not possible, as the result of `getArea` will be a number and numbers don't have `call` method, only [`Function` objects have that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)). But, you should be invoking the `getArea` function itself, like this

```
var area = Rectangle.prototype.getArea.call(this);
```

Comment: Oh, it's called on variable, where function is stored, not on the result of function. Thanks, really much, now i feel little stupid that i didn't get it. Thanks once more! :)